# Broccoli serve does not livereload ember app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am using [ember-cli](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli) for my current ember project, I start the server using `broccoli serve` however livereload does not work and I need to refresh the page everytime I make changes. What is the correct way to use livereload with ember-cli and broccoli?

Comment: does the command line end? or does it keep serving the page?  Is it opening a web view for you, or are you opening it yourself?

Comment: Commandline does not end, it serves the page on localhost:4200. It does not open a web view, I open it myself and everything works on refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `ember server` for your ember-cli projects.

Comment: I'm using "ember server" but the live reload doesn't work. I simply go to the application template change the <h2> content and nothing happens :(

Comment: @Denzo you should probably open up a new question for this or go check out the issues on ember-cli.

Comment: @Denzo Did you figure out in the end what the problem was with the live-reload?

Comment: Looking around and in this issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439380/live-reload-not-working-with-ember-cli, it was a problem with node and npm that was causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Live reload should work out of the box from ember-cli.
To fix the live reload problem try updating the version of ember-cli.

To use

```
broccoli serve
broccoli build
```

you can do the following:

**Install broccoli-cli globally**

```
npm install -g broccoli-cli
```

**Go to the root of your project where you want to run broccoli commands and do the following**

```
npm install --save-dev broccoil
```

Then **broccoli build** & **broccoli serve** should work for your project according to brocfile.js