# live-reload not working with ember-cli

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, ember-cli, livereload

```
ember new foo-proj
cd foo-proj
ember s
```

Now the server is running. But when I edit a file e.g foo-proj/app/index.html **live-reload does not reload**!

I'm running:

- node v0.10.31
- npm 1.4.23

I've been asking around on the #ember-cli channel but no luck.
I seem to be the only one with this problem.

Comment: What version of ember-cli?

Comment: @Dhaulagiri When I run npm ls ember-cli -g
I get /usr/local/lib
└── ember-cli@0.0.40 
But also a lot of unmet dependencies http://imgur.com/2t0wDK7

Comment: How did you go about install node/npm along with ember-cli?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869083/ember-cli-live-reload-not-working/38408895#38408895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally **got live-reload working**.
I had to do some rigorous stuff though which does unfort not explain what the problem was.
I resolved the issue by completely removing node and npm  and then [reinstalling](http://thechangelog.com/install-node-js-with-homebrew-on-os-x/) it by running `brew install node`

@wenincode pointed me to a link to [uninstall node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x/11178106#11178106) and a link to [uninstall npm](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/removing-npm.html)