# ember cli and livereload: how to get it to work?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, livereload

I can't for the life of me get livereload to work with my ember cli project. This is the first time I try livereload, so I don't know if this problem is specific to ember cli, or if my Mac environment is not set up for it.

Here is what I have installed

```
$ ember --version:
  version: 0.0.46
  node: 0.10.32
  npm: 1.4.27
```

Here is how I got everything running:

```
$ ember new foo-bar
$ cd foo-bar
$ ember server
version: 0.0.46
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
```

Navigating to `http://localhost:4200` in Chrome shows me the ember app.

Now if I make changes to 'application.hbs' and then save it, the browser doesn't update.  Is there anything special I need to do to enable livereload?

I realize that this question is similar to [live-reload not working with ember-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439380/live-reload-not-working-with-ember-cli), but the answer to that question doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/2100) with 0.0.46 at the moment.  You can manually add this script tag to `app/index.html` to work around it.

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: with the new ember-cli. you need to edit .ember-cli file and you have to add `"liveReload": true`