# Livereload with ember-cli

Tags: ember-cli, livereload

I'm trying to setup livereload in a brand new ember app created with ember-cli

after using

```
ember new app
```

and setting up the .ember-cli file:

```
{
    "port": 9000,
    "liveReload": true
}
```

I've launched
    ember server

in the console I can see:

```
version: 0.0.46
Livereload server on port 40529
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:9000

Build successful - 1939ms.
```

but

- the browser does not open automatically (I have to manually navigate to localhost:9000)
- the browser does not refresh after updating for example application.hbs template

(I use latest chrome)

There is something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think the browser will open automatically, but the live-reload issue is a known issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049571/ember-cli-and-livereload-how-to-get-it-to-work/26051995#26051995

Comment: Great! Thank you, I was only able to find posts about disabling livereload

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what was going on in September 2014, but the live-reload is on by default in the current builds. You definitely need to open your browser yourself though. Most commonly, users forget to npm sass or stylus and wonder why it's not working - but that is another issue.